# Squaring an Inequality $\,-x > 2\,.$

Tags: inequality

If I have the inequality $\,-x>2\,,\,$ am I allowed to square both sides of this inequality?

I'm thinking that since $-x$ is greater than $2$, then $-x$ must be positive, and since $2$ is positive, both sides are positive meaning I am allowed to square both sides.

Is this true?

Comment: Your reasoning seems sound. Just remember that later inequalities might not make it obvious that you needed $-x$ positive to get there.

Comment: $-3\lt 2$ but $9\not\lt 4$ so, in general, you cannot square both sides of an inequality and preserve the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you squared boths sides, you get

$\displaystyle x^2 \gt 4$

Solving this inequality leads to

$\displaystyle x \in ({{-\infty},-2}) \cup ({2, {\infty}})  $

But your original inequality has the solution

$\displaystyle x \in  ({{-\infty},-2}) $

So technically, you can square but be careful as you get extra solutions too!

P.S. As you have already pointed that

$\displaystyle -x \gt 0$

You can reject the 2nd part of the solution after squaring